# JQuery use in a Firefox extension

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon

I'm attempting to build an extension which creates div elements and uses jQuery to allow them to be subsequently dragged/resized by the user. I don't think I'm importing the jQuery files correctly however as any jQuery statements I use as part of my overlay.js file do absolutely nothing.

I've added the following lines to my overlay.xul:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="jquerylib.js" />
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="jquery-ui.js" />
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="jquery-ui.css" />
```

However I am unsure what additional steps I need to take to allow functions in my overlay.js file to make use of these.

Thank You

Comment: It is a bad idea to use jquery-ui with XUL instead of HTML documents. A lot of stuff is going to break, e.g. IIRC jquery-ui assumes the default namespace is html, when it is xul instead, affecting stuff like `.createElement`, `.setAttribute`. Also, jquery-ui wasn't really written to run in a context with elevated privileges. You're better of using a XUL `<iframe type="content`>`, and have your jquery-ui stuff in there along with some HTML.

Comment: @nmaier Interesting thought, I've never tried to use an iframe in this way before. Would that still allow the div elements to be displayed over the top of an existing webpage? I'm essentially trying to implement a similar functionality to: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery-resize-drag/ in my extension but with notes being generated on the fly via clicking a button on the firefox toolbar.

Comment: Sure. You can insert the iframe into the XUL or the actual tab  content HTML DOM and position it as needed.

Comment: @nmaier Sorry to be a pest, but could you possibly show me an example of how that might be implemented? In all my attempts all I've managed to do is create another webpage inside a smaller window on the main page, whereas ideally for the extension I'd want to be able to create the resizeable div elements on the main page using a seperate jQuery enabled html document as the source. Thanks again